# How to create subcategory for Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm using CPT UI and I've manage to create a working custom post type called "Cars"
I would like to have "Sub Custom Post Type" like "Honda" for example and models like "M1", "M2", "M3" related to "Honda".

So if I click on Honda it will display the models.
How can I achieve the same concept of POST+CATEGORY+SUBCATEOGRY for custom post type 
 (i.e Cars+Honda+M1)

Answer (score 3):

WordPress doesn't support nested post types, though you can created hierarchical types similar to the Core "Page" type. However, what you are describing, including this sample "POST+CATEGORY+SUBCATEOGRY" is a [custom taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) for your Car post type. The Codex has examples, but you would need something like this (roughly, I am sure this needs tweaked):

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_tax' );

function create_book_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'make',
        'cars',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Make' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'make' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#user-contributed-notes

Answer (score 0):

yeah as answered by **@s_ha_dum** wordpress doesn't support the nested post type you can achieve it by xreating the custom taxonomy and by using parent child relation you can acheive your scenario. I am explaning the code as below.

It might be helpful to you.

```
     add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
        function create_post_type() {
register_taxonomy('car', 'cars', array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => _x( 'Car Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                'singular_name' => _x( 'Car -Category', 'Car Category' ),
                'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Car Categories' ),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Car Categories' ),
                'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Car Category' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Car Category:' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Car Category' ),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Car Category' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Car Category' ),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Car Category Name' ),
                'menu_name' => __( 'Car Categories' ),
            ),

            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'car', 
                'with_front' => false, 
                'hierarchical' => true 
            ),
        ));

    register_post_type( 'cars',
            array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Cars' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Cars' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Cars' ),
            'name_admin_bar' => __( 'Cars' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'Group of Companies' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New Car' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'Add New Car' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Car' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Car' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Car' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array("title", "editor", "thumbnail")
            )
            );
```